# Issues with Trac (installed with BitNami)

Tags: configuration, bug-tracking, trac, bitnami

I'm facing some problems after installing Trac on my Windows 7 Ultimate 64bits using BitNami.
The Issues are:

1. Subversion Control
   During the installation process, when the BitNami setup asks for the project repository directory, it only accept if you write a path that doesn't exist, otherwise you can't continue. So i got forced to point the path to "C:\Repositories\TRAC" (a new folder) instead of "C:\Repositories\DBG" (where the repository of the project that i was creating really are). So, after the installation, I've changed the trac.ini file at the key

   ```
   [trac]
   repository_dir = C:\Repositories\TRAC
   repository_type = svn
   ```

to

```
    [trac]
    repository_dir = C:\Repositories\DBG
    repository_type = svn
```

And now, when I login to the DBG project in Trac, it warns:

> Warning:  Can't synchronize with the
>   repository (The 'repository_dir' has
>   changed, a 'trac-admin resync'
>   operation is needed.). Look in the
>   Trac log for more information.

When I go to cmd the following happens:

```
C:\Users\Fernando>cd\

C:\>cd C:\Program Files\BitNami Trac Stack\trac\Scripts

C:\Program Files\BitNami Trac Stack\trac\Scripts>trac-admin resync
Welcome to trac-admin 0.11.6
Interactive Trac administration console.
Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Edgewall Software

Type:  '?' or 'help' for help on commands.

Trac [C:\Program Files\BitNami Trac Stack\trac\Scripts\resync]> resync
Failed to open environment. [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Fi
les\\BitNami Trac Stack\\trac\\Scripts\\resync\\VERSION'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\bitnami trac stack\trac\lib\site-packages\Trac-0.11.6-p
y2.5.egg\trac\admin\console.py", line 177, in env_open
    self.__env = Environment(self.envname)
  File "c:\program files\bitnami trac stack\trac\lib\site-packages\Trac-0.11.6-p
y2.5.egg\trac\env.py", line 209, in __init__
    self.verify()
  File "c:\program files\bitnami trac stack\trac\lib\site-packages\Trac-0.11.6-p
y2.5.egg\trac\env.py", line 277, in verify
    fd = open(os.path.join(self.path, 'VERSION'), 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files\\BitNami Trac S
tack\\trac\\Scripts\\resync\\VERSION'

C:\Program Files\BitNami Trac Stack\trac\Scripts>
```

What it should be?

2-Configuring Logo:
I can't find where to place my project logo to be shown in left-top corner!
at the header_logo key:

```
    [header_logo]
    alt = DBG
    height = 50
    link = http://localhost:801/trac/DBG
    src = ITINT150.png
    width = 150
```

i've placed the ITINT150.png file in the same folder as trac.ini for testing (obviously i wasn't going to leave it there), but trac doesn't find it, looking at the html code of the link tag generated, it points to: src="/trac/DBG/chrome/common/ITINT150.png", but where is this folder located, so i can place the image there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

For the resync, the first argument to trac-admin is the trac environment directory.  So run

```
trac-admin <path-to-trac-environment> resync
```

As of Trac 0.12, the above command changed to:

```
trac-admin <path-to-trac-environment> repository resync <repository-name or '*'>
```

For the logo, set the src to `site/ITINT150.png`, and put `ITINT150.png` into the `<path-to-trac-environment>/htdocs` directory.

Comment: @retracile: the logo is fine now, but when I try to run the command 

"C:\Program Files\BitNami Trac Stack\trac\Scripts>trac-admin C:\TRAC\DBG resync"

i get a message saying "The program can't start because libapr-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem"

Comment: @Tufo: That sounds like there's something wrong with the Subversion install.  I'd suggest asking a new question for that issue; I don't know enough about BitNami or Windows to be of much help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @retracile's solution but I received a "Command not found" message from trac-admin.  This is what eventually worked for me:

```
trac-admin </path/to/trac/env> repository resync "*"
```

That last argument specifies the repository to resync and can be switched with the name of a specific repo (presumably with the quotes intact; I didn't try it) if you don't want to resync all repos.  See here for details: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAdmin